# eigenvalues of a simple RGB image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to replicate the results of an image treatment algorithm I saw in a paper.

An important step is to calculate the eigenvalues of an squared **image**

When reading this I thought they may mean the eigenvalues of each channel (i.e R G and B) as they are using colored images.

However, as mentioned in the paper, a squared image actually

> defines a square matrix in the three-dimensional RGB color space, from which three eigenvectors, orthogonal to one another in
> the three-dimensional RGB color space, can be calculated in
> the traditional manner. Within the context presented herein, the eigenvectors point in the direction of color change. The
> eigenvector having the largest eigenvalue points in the direc
> tion of the most amount of color change, while the other
> eigenvectors, by definition, point in orthogonal directions that
> are also orthogonal to one another.

Which makes sense. Then I started looking for tools for doing this calculation. I found solutions on OpenCV and Numpy, but I got troubles with both:

- OpenCV's eigen():

```
img = cv2.imread("/home/my_user/Desktop/DSC02654.jpeg")
roi = img[0:10, 0:10, :]
roi = np.float32(roi)

print(roi.dtype) # float32
print(roi.shape) # (10, 10, 3)

res = cv2.eigen(roi)
```

With this I get `error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp:1390: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F in function 'eigen'` any clue? the type seems right.

- Numpy's eigvals():

```
#same roi variable
a = LA.eigvals(roi)
```

Here I get `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`. Which means numpy is not calculating the values over a space with 3D elements (I tried using only one channel and I get the values) any clue on a numpy's method that accepts this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe the idea is to put all your pixels in a list, so you compute the eigenvectors of a 2D matrix, being the first dimensions pixel, the second color. Perhaps that is the error in the second is that you are not using the right function, I'd use `np.linalg.eig()`, and in the first case is that likely your jpg returns uint values, not floats, you need to cast.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm casting :) (justed adited the question), but I get the same error on OpenCV, I'll test `np.linalg.eig()`

Comment: You sound like if it is the RGB part that makes it mysterious. Do I take you know what the "eigenvalue of an image" is? I teach linear algebra, and I don't. How would you do this with black&white images? Or separately with each channel?

Comment: The closest thing that could come to mind, is to compute a correlation matrix, and then eigenvalues of that. So, performing a PCA on the image. But even so, you need to define to do what (that is done with multiple samples of something. For example, you could do a PCA on all colors of an image. To then deduce something from the main dimensions)

Comment: So my real question is: what is this all about? Is this about color representation? (your quotation seems to indicate so. But if so, then, it is strange that you even considered the possibility to treat each channel separately: then you would have no information). Or even more direct question: what paper?

Comment: The partial quote (again, hard to make any sense of it without context) seems to be not a recipe. But the definition of a 3x3 matrix. In a 3 dimensional color space (so the vector space of triplets )r,g,b)), they want to define a squared matrix (so a 3x3 matrix), whose 3 eigenvectors (if there are 3) are orthogonal. Why this matrix, we can't know from this partial quote. We don't know what they are trying to do (and, btw, we don't know what you are trying to do). Plus, they seem to ignore the fact that "orthogonal" is subjective to an euclidean space.

Comment: @chrslg you have a point let me share this: ` In a digital image, the above-de
scribed directional color changes can result in the color values
of individual pixels varying in a directional manner. When
those color values of the individual pixels are expressed as
points in a multi-dimensional color-space, directional
changes in the color can be quantified mathematically through eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues. `

Comment: @chrslg If I understand, the eigenvectors should describe the direction in which the color changes.

Comment: @chrslg and what I'm trying to find is the largest eigenvector, which should give me the direction in which the color changes

Comment: Unless you are really a eigenvector-geek, that can't be what your are trying to do. That is a mean you want to use, and with which you expect to achieve an end. My question was "which end". But if that is secret, no problem. My main goal in asking that was to understand if we were talking about image representation of color representation. And your last comment confirmed my intuition: this has nothing to do with image. Just its pixels colors. The image here, is just a bag of pixels.

Comment: For example, you seemed (not sure, but why would have you mentioned it otherwise) to think important the fact that image is squared. Which seems to indicate (and some part of your question too) that you are trying to extract a "square matrix" from a "square image". And that would be easy from your point of view if the image was 1-channel (then, you have the square matrix directly), but not with 3-channels. Am I wrong?

Comment: It has nothing to do with that. And even if there were only 1 channel, you could do nothing with the image. Sure, it is a 2d array of numbers, with same length in both dimension. So you can call `eig` on it, and something with come out. But that something will have no meaning.

Comment: So hard to say without better understanding of the real goal, and without the paper. But my bet is what is intended here is a PCA of all pixels in the image. Or something in that nature. So that the main compoments of the colorspace (according to the PCA) says something about how the color in distributed in the image. For example, you may discover that axes `(1,0,½)` contains 95% of the variance. Meaning that your image is mainly made of nuance of purple.

Comment: [look](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/b4/67/4c/47ddad9621e804/US20130071016A1.pdf) @chrslg it's not so nice to read :v

Comment: The over all problem is detecting shadows, they use squared ROIs on what they call "super pixels"

Comment: Then (just thinking out loud how I would try to detect shadow with eigenvalues), I think it must be something like trying to compute that locally (in those ROI — square or not). Because in one of those "superpixel" we can assume that there are, often, probably 1 color, and because shadow, roughly, consist to apply a factor α<1 to r,g,b values, computing a PCA in a ROI tells you: 1. if your hypothesis was correct (if this superpixel is overlapping two different color area, then you will have a 2nd non negligible component), 2: what is the main color (main component), 3: what part of the ROI is

Comment: made of the same color, but shadowed.

Comment: I take a look at the paper (I, only now, see that you provided a like in one of your comments)

Comment: The thing is, it is a patent (and an incredibly bad one. Even by the standard of software patents). So it describes nothing. Their goal is to be confusing. It is a patent application to be accurate. I hope it was denied eventually (but I doubt so. US patent office tends to accept any software patent coming from big US company, and deny those coming from somewhere else). The theoretical rule is that this patent is illegal anyway (it describes a purely mathematical method). The practical rule is that it is legal if you put it sufficent effort to pretend it is a hardware device you are protecting

Comment: The classical way to do so is "A device, made of a processor, memory and hard-disk that contains a code that contain this pure software I want to protect". But you have to be a bit subtle. Here, they are not at all. They literaly say that. It is an algorithm. But we patent it, because we had the brillant and novel idea to put it on a device that contains a cpu.

Comment: And more importantly for you, is the fact that normaly what you do in a patent is supposed to be crystal clear (that the deal: in exchange of telling the world how you do it, the world acknowledge that those who want to do the same owe you money).

Comment: This one is not. Again "eigen value of a super pixel" (that is of a subimage) means nothing. After reading the patent, I do confirm what I suspected: it is obvisouly a PCA of a "bag of colors". But, still, it means nothing, even if we can try to guess. Likewise "normalize by intensity", means nothing (in this context). I get it was written by an intern that confuse "normalize" by "divide". But you can't  normalize something that is alone in its space.

Comment: So, it is really badly written. Even for a patent. And not really reproducible (which, again, is supposed to be the cornerstone of patents).

Comment: But the general idea is the one I described earlier (which is another reason the patent should be denied: if the novel idea is the same as the one a random dude on SO think first about when taking about shadow and eigenvalue, then it is not a novel idea, it is part of the art. You can't patent that).

Comment: That is that you split the image into "superpixels" made of pixels of similar colors. Compute (with a PCA, I guess) the main components of the color space inside each super-pixel. Compute the ratio between the eigenvalues of the 2 main components. If that ratio is ∞, that means that you have only 1 color (with intensity variation). If that ratio is 1, that means that you have 2 colors, that are not just different by their intensity). And then you divide that ratio by the overall intensity of the superpixel.

Comment: So, big values are dark area made of only one color (with some variations in the intnsity, but not the hue). Small values are area either made of different hues, or light, or both.

Comment: My bet: nobody at Microsoft probably even tried the idea. It is too poorly written and too confusedly and loosely described to be a real thing that has been implemented. That looks more like a "premptive patent" big tech are generating by thousands: you brainstorm some question (like "how to we detect shadow") in a group of students. You take all the ideas from the brainstorming, and patent them all. Just in case in the future one of these idea happen to be working and valuable.

Comment: @chrslg I think [the patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/84/25/7c/f79e6f931f5da5/US8577170.pdf) was aproved

Comment: Well, that's a shame, but changes nothing. The general idea is the one I described. It is not correctly described. And, to go back to your initial question, notably, "eigen value of an image" has no meaning. There is no such thing. And I am pretty sure that is voluntary fuziness. My bet is that what they had in mind is "eigen vectors/values of the correlation matrix of all pixels in the image" (or in the superpixel). But they avoid to say it, because the more fuzzy, the more future ideas may fall under the patent.

Comment: So, again, for your question: there is no such thing as an eigenvalue/vector of an image. So, no way you can just take an image, and call `eigen` or `eigvals` on it. You have first to compute a 3x3 matrix from which you can compute eigen values and vectors.